# Autofill the git commit author field in PhpStorm

Tags: git, phpstorm, phpstorm-2018.1

Is there a way to set the value of the author field shown in the image, so you don't have to type it in every time?

I checked my git config file but my credentials are already entered correctly there.

The autocomplete knows multiple users, maybe this is causing the problem. Unfortunately, I don't know if and / or how you can reset it...

[image: PhpStorm's commit window with empty author field.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding (because of a confusing UI - this field probably needs to be renamed to smth like **Commit as different user**): the **Author** field should only be filled if the author of the changeset is different from the committer (i.e. if you are not the commit author). If you leave this field empty, code will be committed using the author configured in your git config.

Please vote for [IDEA-178170](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178170) and linked tickets to get the current UI changed

Comment: I agree, the UI could make that more obvious. Unfortunately, @lena your link seems to be dead...

Comment: Ah, sorry:( The link is not dead, but the ticket is only visible to developers:( You can vote for related ticket - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-140986

Comment: The new link works, but apparently only users with an account for your youtrack system can vote...